# subdomain on IIS

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

My website will look something like online store, where every user has his online store as subdomain e.g. `user1.myprojectdomain.com`

we need help that how can Manage sub domains. Do we create a Virtual Directory/application for every user in the IIS on runtime or we can do some thing else

I have created a website `xyz.com` in my iis and created an entry in windows `etc/localhost` as follows

```
xyz.com   127.0.0.1
```

and it is working fine. and then I did added **another** entry to route all sub domains as follows

```
*.xyz.com   127.0.0.1
```

Now I am trying to use abc.xyz.com or any other but it is not working

Comment: You can't use wildcards such as * in the windows hosts file. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/272092/622353. You'll need to add a new entry for each subdomain if you want to access it from the local machine.

Comment: probably belongs on serverfault

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure your DNS is setup to point to your subdomain. This means to make sure you have an A Record in the DNS for your subdomain and point to the same IP.

2) You must add an additional website in IIS 7 named subdomain.site.com

Sites > Add Website
Site Name: subdomain.site.com
Physical Path: select the subdomain directory
Binding: same ip as site.com
Host name: subdomain.site.com

Comment: what do you mean by "make sure you have an A Record in the DNS for your subdomain and point to the same IP"

Comment: I do have entry in host file as i mentioned in the question