# Redirect Url in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to redirect a url in my lcalhost ,as when user types : `mystring.localhost/CI` to `localhost/CI/Mycontroller/Myaction/mystring` in codeigniter .its now showing Server not found and says browser Firefox can't find the server at `www.mystring.localhost`.  How to do this ? Thanks in advance. I have this in my `.htaccess` :

```
    RewriteEngine On     
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mystring\.localhost\CI\
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/CI/Mycontroller/myaction/mystring/$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: i have this in my .htaccess : RewriteEngine On                             RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^string\.localhost\Tests\
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/Tests/string/$1 [R=301], but it seems not working.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working in localhost, so i tried in a hosted site , but it also seemed not working

Answer (score 1):

On Windows edit the file `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` and then append:

```
127.0.0.1 mystring.localhost
```

So it will redirect all requests from `mystring.localhost` to `127.0.0.1`

On Linux is the same syntax but file is at `/etc/hosts`

And then, you must make some `Alias` or `RewriteRule` with `RewriteCond` on Apache  configuration or `.htaccess`.

Comment: Now its redirecting to the localhost itself ,i want it to go a specific controller and action . can i take "mystring" as a variable here ?

Comment: You need to configure it at `.htaccess` or `VirtualHost` on Apache.

Comment: I am looking for the .htaccess , thats okay i htink

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working in localhost, so i tried in a hosted site , but it also seemed not working

Comment: How to use this with .htaccess? im in a stuck now

Answer (score 0):

add to c:\wamp\bin\apache\ApacheYOUVERSION\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *.yourdomain.dev
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/CI"
    ServerName *.yourdomain.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

Find `#Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` in `c:\wamp\bin\apache\ApacheYOUVERSION\conf\httpd.conf` and delete `#` at the beginning

in your `hosts` file: `127.0.0.1     yourdomain.dev`

**add this to your htaccess:**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9-]+).yourdomain.dev [NC]  
RewriteRule ([a-z0-9-]+)(/+.*) index.php/$1/%1$2 [QSA]
```

Comment: No here "mystring" is a variable here , and i have to catch that string in my controller to reuse that , thats what i mean . It wont be "mystring" at everytime.

Comment: Sorry but that's not possible to have natively subdomain in windows, look http://stackoverflow.com/a/9695861/741741

Comment: okay i think it can do with .htaccess : now i tried this : RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9-]+).localhost/Tests [NC]  
    RewriteRule ([a-z0-9-]/?)(.*) index.php/$1/%1/$2 [QSA] ,but its not working

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29490/discussion-between-lighta-and-icecreamsandwich)

Answer (score -1):

So if I understand correctly:

-Someone would type in mystring.localhost/CI, and you would like it to redirect them to a certain page with an action and value?

If so, you can set a page as the index page in \application\config\config.php

Its on line 30:

```
$config['index_page'] = 'Mycontroller/Myaction/mystring';
```

Otherwise in the controller that handles your index just do a redirect in it's __construct function.

There is most likely a solution involving the HTACCESS file but I am not very knowledgeable on that.

Hope this helps!

-Gui