# How do I point a domain back to my own machine? (only for my own browser)

Tags: testing, web, hosts

I want to set up a machine for testing a website before launching it.  Some of the tests require logic in parsing the current host.

I want to be able to test it in my browser but i can only access it through the localhost.

I want to know how to make my browser resolve my domain to 127.0.0.1:80.  (Also I don't want my DNS record to point to my test machine, this should be a local test only).

Also, is there a way to make all sub-domains of my domain access 127.0.0.1:80 as well?

Extra Info --
OS: Windows 7
Browser: Chrome
Web Server: Tomcat 7

Thank You.

EDIT ---
The solution was to add a few lines to the host file:

127.0.0.1      example.com

etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29). It's more than likely what points `localhost` to 127.0.0.1 on your computer.

You can find it at C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts on Windows. Or /etc/hosts on most Linux systems, if you're interested.

Comment: Thanks! Any way to add all sub-domains without explicitly typing them out?

Comment: I think you're stuck typing out every domain. It's a pretty "dumb" system, so no wildcards are allowed. According to [another SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138162/wildcards-in-a-hosts-file) there are DNS proxies you could install which would allow you to accomplish this.

Comment: A DNS proxy sounds a little heavy weight.  I ended up just typing out about 100 sub-domains which should be sufficient for the tests.  thanks again