# Change Project URL Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I would like to be able to debug my ASP.NET MVC application on a domain other than localhost as well as any subdomains, in other words:

http://domain.dev
http://*.domain.dev

I have tried the following:

1. Modify the Hosts file
2. Add a Host record for *.domain.dev that returns 127.0.0.1
3. Change the 'Project Url' in the project properties.

However, nothing is working.  When I start to debug I get a page that either says "Service Unavailable" or "Invalid URL".

What am I missing?

p.s. I am using Visual Studio 2013

Answer (score 19):

For **Visual Studio 2015** the steps in the above answers apply but the applicationhost.config file is in a new location. in your "solution" folder follow the path

```
\.vs\config
```

Within that folder you will see your **applicationhost.config** file

Alternatively you could just search your solution folder for the .config file and find it that way.

I personally used the following configuration:

[image]

With the following in my hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1       jam.net
127.0.0.1       www.jam.net
```

And the following in my applicationhost.config file:

```
<site name="JBN.Site" id="2">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Dev\Jam\shoppingcart\src\Web\JBN.Site" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:49707:" />
            <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:49707:localhost" /> 
    </bindings>
</site>
```

**Remember to run your instance of visual studio 2015 as an administrator!** If you don't want to do this every time I recomend this:

[How to Run Visual Studio as Administrator by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654833/how-to-run-visual-studio-as-administrator-by-default)

I hope this helps somebody, I had issues when trying to upgrade to visual studio 2015 and realized that none of my configurations were being carried over.

Comment: Adding the following line was a mandatory step:
`<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:port#:" />`

Comment: if `unable to connect to web server 'IIS Express'` error occurs, again **make sure you run VS as Administrator**

Answer (score 8):

You need to actually create a new record for each subdomain in the hosts file. You can't use wildcards.

```
127.0.0.1 domain.dev
127.0.0.1 foo.domain.dev
127.0.0.1 bar.domain.dev
```

Although it seems that it can be done with some extra work, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138162/wildcards-in-a-hosts-file) for more details.

You also need to include the port number when accessing the URL. The browser would point to `http://foo.domain.dev:0000`, using the port number assigned in VS, of course.

If you are using the Visual Studio Development Server, that's all there is to it. If using IIS Express, it takes a bit more work.

[image: VS project properties]

Then you need to make sure you have a record in the IIS applicationhost.config file :

```
<site name="YourApplication" id="25">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Path\To\Your\App" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:2750:foo.domain.dev" />
    </bindings>
</site>
```

### Update

```
<site name="DomainProject" id="18">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\William\Source" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:32939:domain.dev" />
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:32939:domain2.dev" />
    </bindings>
</site>
```

Comment: I already had all of those settings (I just rechecked to make sure it was exactly as you have it).  I get the following message: "Unable to launch the IIS Express Web server.  The start URL specified is not valid. http://domain.dev:32939"

Comment: So I got it to work on *.domain.dev by replacing the default localhost site in the applicationhost.config instead of adding a new one.  This takes care of me being able to access the site on multiple subdomains, but what about multiple domains?

Comment: Can you post the `<site>` config that you tried to add and didn't work?

Comment: Doesn't look like any of this applies to VS 2015, since my VS2015 projects don't appear in the config file.

Comment: See my answer bellow for VS2015, there is a new applicationhost.config file location, if you upgraded from 2012 or 2013 you will have both and 2015 won't recognize your changes