# ASP.NET MVC 4 Custom URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, custom-routes

I'm new in MVC and I trying to change the default url from `http://localhost:55920/` to `http://myCustonURL/`

My route config:

```
public class RouteConfig
{        
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );            
    }
}
```

How Can I do it?

Comment: This is nothing to do with MVC routing. You need a domain name and DNS records, etc. etc.

Comment: Do you mean just to debug or do you want a fully working domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will only work on your computer,
but you can achieve it with this

> In Solution Explorer, right-click the name of the Web site project for which you want to specify a Web server, and then click Property Pages.
>   In the Property Pages dialog box, click the Start Options tab.
>   Under Server, click Use custom server.
>   In the Base URL box, type the URL that Visual Studio should start when running the current project.

From [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ar/library/ms178108.aspx) also [Here2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20978686/change-project-url-visual-studio)