# setting up subdomain in url locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, subdomain

I am creating a rails application where we have functionality for registering a new User is there and there we are providing separate sub domain for each user by their user name.
so i want to map
 `user_name.localhost:3000.com` where user_name is dynamic

Comment: You need to adjust your local "hosts" file.  See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138162/wildcards-in-a-hosts-file

Comment: I am using ubuntu system not windows . So for that what has to be done.

Comment: You could use [xip.io](http://xip.io): `user_name.127.0.0.1.xip.io:3000` should work

Answer (score 2):

Run your local development server with [pow](http://pow.cx/). If you symlink the app to the `foo`, than your pages are available under `http://foo.dev`, but also under every other subdomain like `http://bar.foo.dev`. There is no need to register a list of subdomains somewhere.

[prax](https://github.com/ysbaddaden/prax) might be an alternative when you are on linux.

Comment: Pow is great, but only works for Mac, the linux port is ropey to say the least

Answer (score 1):

Access like this. No configuration required

```
user_name.lvh.me:3000
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out.
Actually the application is using subdomain_fu gem for creation of the subdomain and when the user is created the subdomain is name is saved in the db and the can accessed by making configuration into the file `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` and map the ip which is being hit like ;

```
192.xxx.xx.xxx           user_name.your_subdomain _name
```

and hit the url like this ;

```
user_name.your_subdomain _name:3000
```

It is working fine with me doing these steps.
Thanks to all for their valuable feed back.