# OpenShift VM DNS not resolving

Tags: dns, virtual-machine, openshift-origin

I'm new to OpenShift, I wanted to set up a few applications and build them with jenkins.

It all went pretty smoothly until I wanted to actually view my application. I started a simple NodeJS app with a jenkings client enabled.

I followed [this](http://openshift.github.io/documentation/oo_deployment_guide_vm.html) VM deployment guide to the tee.

Well, my host name is not being resolved. I can access my app console with the IP that is spit out when you boot the VM, but when I try to access the apps themselves (ex: http://nodejs-origin.openshift.local/) I get a DNS error.

As per the guide, I ran  "yum install -y nss-mdns" and changed nsswitch.conf to include mdns4. 
It should be noted that I got a bunch of PYURL ERROR 6 messages when running the yum command, but at the end it stated that I already had nss-mdns installed.

Not sure where to go from here, I havent been able to find any answers on the web. Hope you guys can help me out!

P.S
I should also mention that I have tried both NAT and host-only adapters for the VM, with no avail.

P.P.S.
If no one can help me with the DNS issue, perhaps someone knows how to access the individual applications by IP? Please help out, I'm still stuck.

Another clarification just in case: The VM is a fedora 64bit environment, while my host machine is running Windows 7.

Comment: I found a way to get rid of the PYURL errors, but unfortunatly I'm still getting DNS errors. Follow this guide, especially the last comment. http://www.rohitmenon.com/index.php/how-to-fix-pycurl-error-6-couldnt-resolve-host-mirrorlist-centos-org-2/

Comment: I am ring into the same issue as you are but on OSX.  Everything seems to be working fine with the broker (DNS resolves the broker name, can create apps, etc).  I have the same issue when I create an app.  It looks to me like it's not updating the DNS so RCH, SSC, and HTTP all fail/timeout when trying to access the app.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest checking out this post: [Wildcards in a Windows hosts file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138162/wildcards-in-a-hosts-file)

Essentially the problem isn't the inside of the vm.

When you create the vm it creates a virtual network for it to use, that's why you can access it with the local ip it shows. Essentially the virtual machine has turned a portion of your computer into the openshift origin website (as you've noticed), so you're free to create apps. And it sounds like you're at the point where I'm at where we've both successfully created an app. The problem is that the ip is local and wouldn't be associated with a url. So the solution is to add something like localhost, which takes precedence before you get to the internet and points to that particular local ip instead, that way when you click links, or type out the app name your computer will now to direct itself to the right place.

Take the steps described [here](http://mayakron.altervista.org/wikibase/show.php?id=AcrylicHome) for your operating system. Make sure to edit the acrylic proxy's host file so that it reads:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
ipfromvm  *.openshift.local
```

Now you can access the console from broker-origin.openshift.local and apps using their links. It also gives you the freedom to create as many domains as you please inside the vm because as you may have guess the wildcard covers all the urls that end with .openshift.local.

Have fun.