# how to create a dynamic Subdomain with user name after registration in localhost php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I created subdomain like this  **user2**.example.com.

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       user2.localhost
```

and this is the static one

but i need the **user2** will b the  dynaimic  for example if i was registerd with abc(username) my website should b like this abc.example.com

Answer (score 1):

What you are search for is a Wildcard Subdomain. You need to register one at your Domain Reseller (`*.example.com`), but it is not supported at most hosters, i know. For testing on localhost, you need a custom DNS Server. Take a look at [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9695861/2441442).

Then it is depended on the Webserver.

For [Apache](http://steinsoft.net/index.php?site=programming/articles/apachewildcarddomain):

```
<VirtualHost 111.22.33.55>
    DocumentRoot /www/subdomain
    ServerName www.domain.tld
    ServerAlias *.domain.tld
</VirtualHost>
```

For [Nginx](https://serverfault.com/questions/249952/wildcard-vhosts-on-nginx):

```
server {
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  root www/pub;
}

server {
  server_name ~^(.*)\.example\.com$ ;
  root www/pub/$1;
}
```

For [IIS](https://serverfault.com/a/374084):

```
<rule name="CustomRule" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="*.aaa.bbbb.com" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="http://aaa.bbbb.com/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: no no just i am working on localsystem using appache

Answer (score 0):

If you're running your website on Apache its better to check [URL Rewriting Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/) from the Apache documentation out. Also you can try a thing like this :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$           http://www.domain.com/%1/$1 [L,R]
```

If you're running your website on Nginx you can try this:

```
server {
  server_name ~^(.*)\.domain\.com$ ;

  rewrite ^ http://www.domain.com/$1 break;
}
```

Comment: now i had the username how i can i send that value to htaccess?

Comment: if you have .htaccess so may be you're using Apache so try first qoute.

Answer (score 0):

First, we need to configure our DNS settings to make all subdomains resolve to a single address. Then configure Virtual Hosts in the Apache Configuration to save our page and Remember the wildcard.

Check [this tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/basecamp-style-subdomains-with-codeigniter--net-16330) step by step