# Subdomain routing not working on Laravel 5 - WAMPServer

Tags: apache, .htaccess, laravel, routes, wamp

I am trying to implement static and dynamic subdomain routing in my application. It is not working as expected. I am using WAMPServer in my local machine.

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');

Route::group(['domain' => 'api.letsplay.dev'], function () {

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function () {
        Route::get('users', function () {
            return "Success";
        });
    });

});
```

**php artisan route:list** gives this

```
+------------------+----------+----------+------+----------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain           | Method   | URI      | Name | Action                                       | Middleware |
+------------------+----------+----------+------+----------------------------------------------+------------+
|                  | GET|HEAD | /        |      | App\Http\Controllers\WelcomeController@index | guest      |
| api.letsplay.dev | GET|HEAD | v1/users |      | Closure                                      |            |
+------------------+----------+----------+------+----------------------------------------------+------------+
```

**hosts** file has this

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       hosp.dev
127.0.0.1       letsplay.dev
```

I use the **.htaccess** file provided by the laravel framework without any change

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@letsplay.dev
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/letsplay-web/public"
    ServerName letsplay.dev
    ErrorLog "logs/letsplay.dev-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/letsplay.dev-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

When I tried to hit `letsplay.dev` from my browser, It is working as expected. but while trying to hit `api.letsplay.dev/v1/users`, I get `ERR_ICANN_NAME_COLLISION` in Chrome and the below error from IE!

[Forbidden error from IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqRNH.jpg)

Help me to understand what am I missing!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check: [icannwiki](http://icannwiki.com/.dev)

.dev is one of the new proposed gTLDs. We used to work with .dev domains internally, but moved to .local to avoid issues.

Additionally, as chanafdo mentioned in his comments, you can't use wildcards in your windows host file. So you have to specifiy each subdomain as well.

And you should generally avoid having multiple lines with the same ip address in your host file, just add them to the same line, separated by a whitespace:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost letsplay.dev api.letsplay.dev
```

To enable wildcard subdomain support in apache, just specify

```
ServerAlias *.letsplay.dev
```

in your vhost configuration.

Answer (score 1):

First enable the Apache modules `alias_module` and `vhost_alias_module`

Then in your `httpd-vhosts.conf` file add the following.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName letsplay.dev
    ServerAlias api.letsplay.dev
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/letsplay-web/public"
    <directory "c:/wamp/www/letsplay-web/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from all
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Restart WampServer.

Then in your `hosts` file add the following.

```
127.0.0.1 api.letsplay.dev
```

Comment: How to do it for dynamic sub domain routing?

Comment: If you see the ie error screen shot, it is evident that the request is reaching the local wamp server. It is different in chrome.

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic. Do you need to do something like domain folder mapping.

Comment: Please note that windows does not allow wildcards in hosts file. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138162/wildcards-in-a-windows-hosts-file).