# Redirect URL on Windows (local dev environment)

Tags: windows, dns

I'm setting up a local dev environment, as part of this I need to redirect a domain name (including all subdomains) to a local IP address.

I have achieved this on Linux using dnsmasq with this line in the config:
address=/example.com/10.0.19.12

This looks like it will also work on OS X, but I now need the same effect on Windows. How would I get a Windows machine to do this too?

Comment: Add to the host file @ `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` if you can list the individual subdomains

Comment: The idea is to dynamically support any subdomains. Which is why I opted for dnsmasq on Linux.

Comment: Think I just found the answer in the related sidepanel: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138162/wildcards-in-a-windows-hosts-file?rq=1