# Htaccess rewrite url domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, dns

I have an url `localhost/viewprofile.php?username=johngood23` and  I want it to rewritten as `johngood23.localhost` using htaccess.

This is what I tried but failed to do so. 

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.localhost\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ viewprofile.php?username= $1`

Comment: To do this you'll need to manipulate dns and create a virtual host in apache.

Comment: And how do we do that? @ramrider?

Comment: You will, I'm sure, find most of what you want / need in the following StackOverflow post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138162/wildcards-in-a-windows-hosts-file