# How to config Dual DHCP DNS Server on windows with Virtualbox?

Tags: dns, virtualbox

I have a host system with Windows 10 OS.

I installed a Virtualbox and made a Ubuntu server 15.10 as a guest system.

I have a Apache on my Virtualbox.

My host is connected to the Internet through a router.

Usually my LAN on my host has the ip addresses like this:

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet:
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::687b:c091:96f:731c%7
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.1.100
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.1.1
```

And my virtualbox has this ip: 172.16.1.101 through the bridge

When I want to access the webpage in my virtualbox it is sufficient to type

```
172.16.1.101:8080
```

in browser and then I see my index.html page in host.

I want to access this address trough a fake domain like `example.lcl`
I don't want to do that through the `c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` file.
I want to use some local dns server like `Bind` or `Dual DHCP DNS Server` but I don't know how to do that.
As my host OS gets its ip dynamically from router I couldn't set `Dual DHCP DNS Server` to listen my local request to map some fake domains to that destination ip address.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use Acrylic DNS Proxy. You can use wildcards and also dynamic answer with it. More details here:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138162/wildcards-in-a-windows-hosts-file
```