# Apache wildcard virtual host in windows (xampp)

Tags: windows, apache, xampp, vhosts

I'm trying to create a new virtual host where any subdomain will point to the document root.

It needs to be a wild card as new subdomains will be added progmatically.

What I have so far in my vhost config (relevant part):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/test"
     ServerName test.dev
     ServerAlias *.test.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

Windows hosts:

```
127.0.0.1   *.test.dev
```

I'm only able to access test.dev but not a subdomain of it.

Comment: Using acrylic solved the issue so I'll post that link as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Windows host files are not compatible with wildcard domains.

Using the acrylic application as a proxy as described here fixed the issue.

[Wildcards in a Windows hosts file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138162/wildcards-in-a-windows-hosts-file)