# Acrylic DNS Proxy does not work to create dynamically wildcard sub domain

Tags: apache, laravel, proxy, laravel-5.4

In Laravel 5.4 I want to create dynamically subdomain.

According to [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9695861/498504) in SO I followed this instructions to do that:

First I downloaded and installed Acrylic DNS Proxy program. then I added this line at end of Acrylic Host file like this:

```
127.0.0.1 *.loverspay.dev loverspay.dev
```

And added this to **httpd-vhosts** in apache **extra** directory:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost.com
    DocumentRoot 'd:/wamp/www/loverspay/public'
    ServerName loverspay.dev
    ServerAlias *.loverspay.dev
    <Directory 'd:/wamp/www/loverspay/public'>
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Also I changed Preferred DNS Server to **127.0.0.1** in Local Area Connection Properties.

And this is my route to control wildcard subdomain that should show `main` route in larvel :

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{account}.loverspay.dev'], function ($account) {
        Route::get('/', function ($account, $id) {
            return view('home');
        });
    });
```

Now after starting  acrylic DNS proxy when I go to `loverspay.dev` all things worked find But when I want to open `ahmad.loverspay.dev` for example only a `This site can’t be reached` message shown in chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I have used Acrylic before in a project and it worked great, I can't tell what's wrong with your setup but from my project, try the following.

Ensure you have added `127.0.0.1 loverspay.dev` to your etc\hosts file.

For your Acrylic Host file, add just

`127.0.0.1 *.loverspay.dev`

Ensure to restart Acrylic afterwards.

Then for your **httpd-vhosts**, update to

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost.com
    ServerName loverspay.dev
    ServerAlias *.loverspay.dev
    DocumentRoot 'd:/wamp/www/loverspay/public'
    <Directory 'd:/wamp/www/loverspay/public'>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Hope this works.

Comment: I tried and checked your solution many times  but not solved my problem :(

Comment: For anyone else this may help, make sure to add your preferred  DNS to 127.0.0.1  or whatever your local DNS is.